# Laravel - Backpack. Display field from other model

Tags: laravel, crud, relation, laravel-backpack

After many research I couldn't find the answer to my question.
I have a model "Station" with two fields : "name" and "city_id".

In my Station view (in the backpack admin panel) I would like to display city's name (in the model City).

Station and City model are correctly link with hasMany() and belongTo() methods.

How can I set my column in my crud controller to display the name instead of the city id ?

Thank for your help !

Comment: Please post your code, I imagine it's a simple swap of a property

Answer (score 0):

### Station Model

```
<?php

[...] // Namespaces

Class Station {

    [...]

    public function city() {
        $this->belongsTo('App\City');
    }
}
```

### City Model

```
<?php

[...] // Namespaces

class City {

    [...]

    public function station() {
        $this->hasMany('App\Station');
    }
}
```

### Crud Controller

```
<?php

[...] // Namespaces

class CrudController {

    public function sampleFunction() {
        $stations = App\Station::with('city')->all();

        return view('stations', compact('stations'));
    }
}
```

### View

Now you can loop the stations on your view like

```
<ul>
@foreach($stations as $station)
    <li>{{ $station->city->name }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had wrong sight on backpack fields.
Take a look at here.

You can build a [custom view](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/v3.0/docs/crud-fields#section-view) and use this for your other model.

[Can't add field from different table in laravel-backpack CRUD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42849145/cant-add-field-from-different-table-in-laravel-backpack-crud/43037493#43037493)