# Can't add field from different table in laravel-backpack CRUD

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-backpack

I have `libraries`, `townships` and `states` tables in the database (`Library`, `Township`, `State` as model names). 
`Library` is 1-n to `Township` .

**In the `Library`.**

```
public function township(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Township', 'township_id');
  }
```

**In the `Township` Model**

```
public function libraries(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Library');
    }
```

And `Township` is 1-n to `State`.

**In the `Township` Model**

```
public function state()  {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\State', 'state_id');
    }
```

**In the `State` Model**

```
public function townships(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Township');
    }
```

In the Library's create form, I need to get all rows from `State` and fill it to select2 box.
Ofcourse, there's another select2 box for `Township`. It's value will change on selected `State`.

So, the question is I need to add a field like this in my `LibraryCrudController.php`

```
$this->crud->addField([
     'label' => 'State',
     'type' => 'select2',
     'name' => 'state_id', //Should From Township Model. But how?
     'entity' => 'state',
     'attribute' => 'name',
     'model' => "App\State",
   ]);
```

If I did like this,the Error is

```
ErrorException in SchemaException.php line 86:
There is no column with name 'state_id' on table 'libraries'. (View: /home/zugor/code/backpack-crud/vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/fields/select2.blade.php) (View: /home/zugor/code/backpack-crud/vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/fields/select2.blade.php) (View: /home/zugor/code/backpack-crud/vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/fields/select2.blade.php) (View: /home/zugor/code/backpack-crud/vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/fields/select2.blade.php)
```

Is there any solution for this ?
I searched much but found none.

Comment: Did you do that?

Comment: @EdayGonzalez I had wrong idea about Backpack Fileds. It works well with custom view type.